# Determining compactness of the set $S=\{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}:m\in \mathbb N, n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{0\}$ in metric space $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Given a set $S=\{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}:m\in \mathbb N, n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{0\}$. 
My attempt: 
**Claim $1:0$ is a limit point of set $S$.**

Proof: Given any $\epsilon \gt 0, \exists N_\epsilon \in \mathbb N: \frac1{N_\epsilon}\lt \epsilon/2$. Choosing $m,n \ge N_\epsilon$,we have $\frac1{n}\le \frac1{N_\epsilon}\lt \epsilon/2$ and $\frac1{m}\le \frac1{N_\epsilon}\lt \epsilon/2 $. Thus $0\lt\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\lt \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon \gt 0$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $0$ is a limit point of $S$.

**Claim $2$: All elements of set $T=\{1/n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ are also limit points of $S$.**

Proof: Given any $\epsilon \gt 0, \exists M_\epsilon \in \mathbb N: \frac1{M_\epsilon}\lt \epsilon\implies \frac1{m}\lt \epsilon \;\;\forall m\ge M_\epsilon\implies -\epsilon\lt \frac1{m}\lt \epsilon$. Hence for any $\frac1{n}\in T$, we have $\frac 1{n}-\epsilon\lt \frac 1{n}+ \frac1{m}\lt \frac1{n}+\epsilon$. Just as previosuly, it follows that all elements of $T$ are limit points of $S$.

Heine-Borel theorem states that a set $S$ in $\mathbb R$ is compact $\iff S$ is closed and bounded. Indeed, in the present case, $S$ is bounded as $2$ is one upper bound. 
Since, $1/n \notin S$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$, $S$ is not closed and therefore, $S$ can't be compact.

Is my conclusion correct? Thanks.

Edit: How do I show that $S$ does not have limit points except $0$ and $\{1/n: n\in \mathbb N\}$?

Comment: Are you sure that $\frac{1}{n} \notin S$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$? What about $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @JackPfaffinger: for every $1/n, 1/(2n)+1/(2n)$ will do the trick. I think you are right.  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, $T\subseteq S$: for each $\frac1n\in T$ we have $\frac1n=\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n}$. Even if the definition of $S$ were changed to require $m\ne n$, we could write

$$\frac1n=\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n(n+1)}$$

for any $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Thus, if you can show that $0$ and the numbers $\frac1n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ are the only limit points of $S$, you can conclude that $S$ **is** compact. I’ll sketch an argument and let you fill in the details.

Let $x\in\Bbb R\setminus S$. If $x<0$, then $(x-1,0)$ is an open interval around $x$ disjoint from $S$, so $x$ is not a limit point of $S$. Similarly, if $x>2$, then $(2,x+1)$ is an open interval around $x$ disjoint from $S$.

Now suppose that $1<x<2$. Since $\frac1n+\frac1m\le 1$ when $n,k\ge 2$,

$$S\cap(1,2)\subseteq\left\{1+\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\,,$$

and therefore

$$(1,2)\setminus S=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\left(1+\frac1{n+1},1+\frac1n\right)\,,$$

so there is a unique $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\left(1+\frac1{n+1},1+\frac1n\right)$ is an open interval around $x$ disjoint from $S$.

Finally, suppose that $0<x<1$. There is a unique $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that

$$\frac1{n+1}<x<\frac1n\,.$$

Suppose that $\frac1k+\frac1\ell\in S\cap\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)$, with $k\le\ell$.

- Show that $k\le 2n+2$.
- Show that for each positive integer $k\le 2n+2$ there are only finitely many $\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1k+\frac1\ell<\frac1n$.
- Conclude that there are $a,b\in S$ such that $a=\max\{s\in S:s<x\}$ and $b=\min\{s\in S:x<s\}$, so that $(a,b)$ is an open interval around $x$ disjoint from $S$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response sir.  In the block "Now suppose that $1\lt x\lt 2$. Since $1/2+1/2 <1$...", how come $1/2+1/2\lt 1$ and in $S\cap (1,2), $ shouldn't we have $n\in \mathbb Z^+ -\{1\}$?

Comment: @Koro: That was a typo: it was supposed to sat $\frac12+\frac12\le 1$. I’ve changed it a little make the reasoning clearer. You’re right about needing $n\in\Bbb Z^+\setminus\{1\}$, and I’ve fixed that as well; thanks for catching these.

Comment: Just to fill in the details for my understanding: Suppose $x\notin S$. Any $x\ge 2$ and any $x\lt 0$ can't be limit points of $S$. In fact, $\{x: 1\lt x\lt 2\}$ can't also be limit points of $S$. For $x: |x|\lt 1, \exists n: \frac1{n+1}\lt x\lt \frac1{n} $. This $n$ is unique. Plotting this situation on paper shows that $x-\frac1{n+1}\gt 0 \implies \exists m: \frac 1{m+1}\lt x-\frac 1{n+1}\lt \frac 1{m} $. This $m$ is also unique. We choose, $\delta =0.5 (\frac 1{m}-\frac1{m+1})$ and note that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap S$ is empty set. Final para in your answer proves this fact rigorously.

Comment: @Koro: While it’s true that when $\frac1{n+1}<x<\frac1n$ there is a unique $m$ such that $\frac1{m+1}<x-\frac1{n+1}<\frac1m$, this doesn’t clearly rule out the possibility that there might be some $\frac1k+\frac1\ell$ between $\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{m+1}$ and $\frac1{n+1}+\frac1m$. The argument that I suggested does that: if we know that $S$ has only finitely many points between $\frac1{n+1}$ and $\frac1n$, one of them has to be closest to $x$, even if we don’t know which one it is.

Comment: I made a mistake there. I want to choose $\delta =0.5 min \{|\frac 1{m+1}+\frac 1{n+1}-x|, \frac 1{m}+\frac 1{n+1} -x\}$. So that $(x-\delta, x+\delta)\cap S$ is an empty set. But I understand your point, writing only there exists unique $m,n$ is not enough. It must also be mentioned that $n$ is maximum value of integers which does $\frac1{n+1}\lt x\lt \frac1{n}$ etc. This will ensure arrest of finitely many elements (may be $0$ also) of S between $\frac1{n+1}$ and $ \frac1{n}$.

Comment: @Koro: No, there’s only one $n$ such that $\frac1{n+1}<x<\frac1n$. Then we show that there are only finitely many members of $S$ in that same interval, and we can let $\delta$ be the minimum of all $|x-s|$ with $s\in S\cap\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I understand it now. 

Comment: @Koro: Excellent! You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

Let $x \not\in S$. We are going to show $x$ can't be a limit point of $S$.  As $S$ is bounded below by $0$ and above by $2$ we don't need so consider $x \le 0$ or $x \ge 2$.

So $x \ne \frac 1m = \frac 1{2m}+\frac 1{2m}$

Now $x > 0$ So there is a minimal $m \in \mathbb N$ so that $\frac 1m < x$.  If $m> 1$ then $\frac 1m < x < \frac 1{m-1}$ and if $m= 1$ then $\frac 1m = 1 < x$

Now $x -\frac 1m > 0$ so there is a minimal $n\in \mathbb N$ so that $\frac 1m + \frac 1n < x$.  And again if $n>1$ then $\frac 1m +\frac 1n < x < \frac 1m + \frac 1{n-1}$ and if $n=1$ then $\frac 1m + \frac 1n = \frac 1m + 1 < x$. (but it's not actually possible for $n = 1$)

It's easy to see that if $m =1$ then $\frac 1m + \frac 1n < x < 2$ so $n > 1=m$, and if $m> 1$ then $\frac 1m +\frac 1n < x < \frac 1{m-1}$ so $\frac 1n < \frac 1{m-1} + \frac 1m = \frac 1{(m-1)m} < \frac 1m$ and $n > m$.  SO $n > m\ge 1$.  So $\frac 1m +\frac 1n < x < \frac 1m +\frac 1{n-1}$

Now pick an $r$ so that $r < \min(x - (\frac 1m +\frac 1n),  (\frac 1m +\frac 1{n-1})- x)$

The $B_r(x)$ can't contain any points of $S$.

So $x$ is not a limit point of $S$ and then only limit points of $S$ (if any) are in $S$ so $S$ is closed.

(I say "if any" because we did nothing to *find* any limit points and we don't care.  If we actually cared we can see all $\frac 1m$ (including $1$) and $0$ are limit points [as there are infinitely many $\frac 1m + \frac 1n$ is any $B_r(\frac 1m)$] and for any $\frac 1m +\frac 1n\ne \frac 1t; t\in \mathbb N$ we can use a similar argument above is not t limit point.)

====

On the other hand a proof by finite subcover could be easier:

If $0 \in U$, an open set, then all but a finite number of $\frac 1t$ are in $U$.  For each of these finite number $\frac 1m \not \in U$ if $\frac 1m \in V_m$, then all but a finite number of $\frac 1m +\frac 1s \not \in V_m$. If each of these finite number of $\frac 1m + \frac 1{n_m}$ is in an open set $W_{m,n_m}$ then we have covered $S$.

For any open cover, $\mathscr U$, of $S$ we can find a $U\in \mathscr U$  so that $0 \in U$.  Then we can have a finite number of $\frac 1m \not \in U$ and we can find a finite number of $V_m \in \mathscr U$ so that $\frac 1m \in V_m$.  And for each of those we can find a finite number of $n_m$ so that $\frac 1m +\frac 1{n_m}\not \in V_m$ we can find a $W_{m,n_m}$ so that $\frac 1m +\frac 1{n_m} \in W_{m,n_m}$.

And $\{U\} \cup \{V_m\}\cup \{W_{m,n_m}\}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathscr U$.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir  . Finite subcover argument is also amazing. For choosing $r$ though, there might be a  possibility that $(\frac1{m}+\frac1{n},\frac1{m}+\frac1{n-1})$ contains finitely many elements of S so $r$ should be chosen accordingly @Brian M. Scott also clarifies for his answer given below.